# Javascript code works locally, but not on server

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I made a simple page on google maps, showing a bunch of pointers.
When I try this code on my PC, it works without any problem.

But, when I upload the files on my server, the Google Map dosen't show up, and I get the followings errors :

```
SyntaxError: invalid property id variables.js:1 
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement fonctions.js:1 
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement villes.js:1 
ReferenceError: initialisation is not defined index.html:1
```

Any idea what I could have done wrong ?
Thanks in advance :)

My code :

index .html

```
    <head>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <title>Les dés de Monique</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" ></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./initialisation.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./variables.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./fonctions.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="./villes.js"></script>


    </head>


    <body onload="initialisation()">

            <div id="panel">
                <input id="address" type="textbox" value="Bains de Bretagne, France">
                <input type="button" value="Ajouter" onclick="coderadresse()">
            </div>

        <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
    </body>



</html>
```

variables .js

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var map;
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(46.1100, 2.1939);
var bounds;


var myOptions = 
{
    //Controles de l'utilisateur
    keyboardShorcuts: true,
    draggable: true,
    scrollwheel: true, 
    disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
    disableDefaultUI:true,


    //Affichage (ou non) des boutons
    navigationControl: true,
    mapTypeControl: true,
    zoomControl: true,
    panControl: true,
    overviewMapControl: false,
    rotateControl: false,
    scaleControl: false, 
    streetViewControl: false,
    center: latlng,


    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN    
};

var styles = 
[
    {
            featureType: "localities",
            elementType: "labels",
            stylers: 
            [
                { 
                    visibility: "off" 
                }
            ]
    },
    {
            featureType: "road",
            stylers: 
            [
                { 
                    visibility: "off" 
                }
            ]
    }
];
```

villes .js

```
var villes = 
[
"Tirana",
"Berlin",
"Andorre-la-Vieille",
"Vienne",
"Bruxelles",
"Minsk",
"Sarajevo",
"Sofia",
"Nicosie",
"Zagreb",
"Copenhague",
"Madrid",
"Tallinn",
"Helsinki",
"Paris",
"Athènes",
"Budapest",
"Dublin",
"Reykjavik",
"Rome",
"Riga",
"Vaduz",
"Vilnius",
"Luxembourg",
"Skopje",
"La Valette",
"Chisinau",
"Monaco",
"Podgorica",
"Oslo",
"Amsterdam",
"Varsovie",
"Lisbonne",
"Prague",
"Bucarest",
"Londres",
"Moscou",
"Belgrade",
"Bratislava",
"Ljubljana",
"Stockholm",
"Berne",
"Kiev",
]

var coordonneesvilles = 
[
new google.maps.LatLng(41.33165, 19.83179999999993),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.519171, 13.406091199999992),
new google.maps.LatLng(42.50631740000001, 1.521835499999952),
new google.maps.LatLng(48.2081743, 16.37381890000006),
new google.maps.LatLng(50.8503396, 4.351710300000036),
new google.maps.LatLng(53.9, 27.56666670000004),
new google.maps.LatLng(43.8562586, 18.413076300000057),
new google.maps.LatLng(42.6978388, 23.32166970000003),
new google.maps.LatLng(35.1666667, 33.366666699999996),
new google.maps.LatLng(45.8130293, 15.977894900000024),
new google.maps.LatLng(55.6760968, 12.568337100000008),
new google.maps.LatLng(40.4167754, -3.7037901999999576),
new google.maps.LatLng(59.43696079999999, 24.75357459999998),
new google.maps.LatLng(60.17332440000001, 24.941024800000037),
new google.maps.LatLng(48.856614, 2.3522219000000177),
new google.maps.LatLng(37.9837155, 23.72930969999993),
new google.maps.LatLng(47.497912, 19.04023499999994),
new google.maps.LatLng(53.3498053, -6.260309699999993),
new google.maps.LatLng(64.13533799999999, -21.89521000000002),
new google.maps.LatLng(41.8929163, 12.482519899999943),
new google.maps.LatLng(56.9496487, 24.10518639999998),
new google.maps.LatLng(47.14136999999999, 9.520700000000033),
new google.maps.LatLng(54.6871555, 25.279651400000034),
new google.maps.LatLng(49.815273, 6.129583000000025),
new google.maps.LatLng(41.9973462, 21.42799560000003),
new google.maps.LatLng(35.89779, 14.51410599999997),
new google.maps.LatLng(47.02685899999999, 28.84155099999998),
new google.maps.LatLng(43.73841760000001, 7.42461579999997),
new google.maps.LatLng(42.442575, 19.26864599999999),
new google.maps.LatLng(59.9138688, 10.752245399999993),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.3702157, 4.895167899999933),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.2296756, 21.012228700000037),
new google.maps.LatLng(38.7252993, -9.150036399999976),
new google.maps.LatLng(50.0755381, 14.43780049999998),
new google.maps.LatLng(44.4325, 26.103888900000015),
new google.maps.LatLng(51.51121389999999, -0.11982439999997041),
new google.maps.LatLng(55.7512419, 37.6184217),
new google.maps.LatLng(44.8205556, 20.462222200000042),
new google.maps.LatLng(48.1458923, 17.107137299999977),
new google.maps.LatLng(46.05645089999999, 14.50807020000002),
new google.maps.LatLng(59.32893000000001, 18.064910000000054),
new google.maps.LatLng(46.9479222, 7.444608499999958),
new google.maps.LatLng(50.4501, 30.523400000000038),
]
```

initialisation .js

```
//Fonction d'initialisation de la carte, selon des valeurs précisées
function initialisation() 
{
   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
   centrercarte();
   placermarqueurs();
}
```

fonctions .js

```
function centrercarte()
{
    bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();


    for (var i = 0 ; i < coordonneesvilles.length ; i++)
    {

        bounds.extend(coordonneesvilles[i]);
    }

    map.fitBounds(bounds);
}

function placermarqueurs()
{
    for (var i = 0 ; i < coordonneesvilles.length ; i++)
    {


            var optionsmarqueur =
            {
                position: coordonneesvilles[i],
                map: map,
                draggable: false,
                clickable:false,
                title:villes[i],
             }


         var marqueurville = new google.maps.Marker(optionsmarqueur);
    }
 }


function coderadresse() 
{
    var address = document.getElementById('address').value;

    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status)
    {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
    {

      //Cette partie là devient inutile si on rafraichit la carte par redirections successives.  
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
      {
          map: map,
          position: results[0].geometry.location

      });


      envoyerdonnees(address, results[0].geometry.location);

     } 

     else 
     {
      alert('Désolé, le géocodage a échoué... ( ' + status + ')');
     } 
  });
}

function envoyerdonnees(nom, coordonnees)
{
    nom = ("\""+nom+"\", \n");
    coordonnees = ("new google.maps.LatLng"+coordonnees+", \n");    

    //redirection vers la fonction de traitement de fichier
    document.location.href=("./traitementfichier.php?nom="+nom+"&coordonnees="+coordonnees); 
 }
```

Comment: We need to see the code the error refers to.

Comment: My dev machine always matches my prod machine in regards to os, software versions, etc, not physical hardware but OS

Comment: Sorry, I didn't upload the code because I was hoping for an "evident-solution-i-missed" like the binary/ascii thing.

I will edit my original message in a few seconds to add the files.
Anyway, guys you answer very fast ! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Check if the FTP-Upload had correct settings. Maybe you uploaded the files in "binary" mode instead of "ascii" mode.

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion: the body "onload" is quite unsure, because the code will be executed when the parser his this line of code. So if you refer to the "map_canvas" the operation could fail. On your PC the source code is loaded in milliseconds - so this doesn't hurt, but from your server (depending on your internet speed) this download could take too long.

Try to implement jQuery as well with the following line:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

An then use:

```
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  initialisation()
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, but I still get the same errors. :/
It's kinda frustrating, because I have no idea what could be the cause of the problem...